# ¿Cómo se traduciría el término "edgy as fuck" al español?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, jerga-internet, vulgaridades

He leído mucho este término en muchos foros de discusión en inglés, quisiera saber si saben cuál término en español podría ser un buen equivalente a este.

Ojo, en los foros lo utilizan con su acepción de "buscapleitos", "provocador", "atrevido", "rudo", "bravucón" y también con la acepción de "vanguardista".

Comment: Es un insulto sarcástico, muy común en los sitios de Internet americanos, viene siendo como en español criticamos a las "únicas y diferentes"

Answer (score 7):

*Edgy as fuck* es basicamente un insulto en estos días.

"Wow, that was edgy" o "he's edgy as fuck" son maneras sarcásticas de indicar que una persona es... de una manera, dramática.

Si un joven postea en su facebook cosas como "eso de que tengas que llorar en la ducha..." eso es edgy. "el viento se lleva mis palabras... Se las lleva a los oídos de ella" eso es *edgy*. Un joven que viste de negro diciendo "nadie me entiende, soy especial. Soy diferente a todos los jóvenes de hoy en día..." eso es *Edgy as fuck* y hasta da un poco de "cringe" (vergüenza ajena).

Puede que si encuentras la palabra "edgy" en algún pedazo de literatura, el significado sea más parecido al original/necesites guiarte por un diccionario. Pero si alguien que está en contacto con la internet, especialmente aquellos jovenes y adultos que pasan el tiempo en comunidades de habla inglesa, se encuentra con la palabra "edgy" refiriéndose a alguien, o dice que algo es "edgy as fuck" o "edgy AF" (que es la abreviación), estate seguro que es un comentario sarcástico, y con aires de provocar la risa en algunos, e irritar al que recibe el comentario.

Lo digo por experiencia, siendo alguien en contacto continuo con la internet y solo habla con gente que habla inglés, pues ese es mi primer idioma.

Answer (score 6):

Como bien indicas `edgy` parece tener dos significados. Uno como `vanguardista` y otro como `tenso, nervioso o irritable`.

> **Edgy** (adjective)
>
> 1. tense, nervous, or irritable.
>
> "He became edgy and defensive (synonyms:   tense, nervous, on edge, anxious, apprehensive, uneasy, unsettled)
>
> 2. (informal) at the forefront of a trend; experimental or avant-garde.
>
> "Their songs combine good music and smart, edgy ideas"
>    (synonyms: cutting-edge, on-the-edge)

Para el segundo significado, `vanguardista` me parece la mejor opción. Para el primero yo usaría `tenso`, que recoge todas esas connotaciones de nervioso, ansioso, al borde de un ataque de nervios, etc.

No entiendo las traducciones tipo "buscapleitos", "provocador", "atrevido", "rudo" o "bravucón" que dices que ofrecen otros foros. Está claro por la definición que `edgy` refleja nervios y ansiedad. Ese comportamiento puede ser "rudo" pero no "bravucón" o "provocador". Algo muy novedoso puede ser provocador, pero no necesariamente. Así que creo que esas son simplemente malas traducciones.

El `as fuck` se usa para reforzar o resaltar el significado del adjetivo.

Dados los significados de `edgy` yo favorecería el uso de `de cojones`.

> Está ansioso de cojones.
>
> Se puso defensivo de cojones cuando le sacaron ese tema.
>
> Esto es vanguardista/novedoso de cojones.

Comment: Ninguna de las dos acepciones mencionadas por user478249 es la de los nervios.  También te equivocas con "as fuck" que, como explica @giorno, pone una capa de sarcasmo encima de "edgy."  Esta respuesta no es correcta.

Comment: @aparente001, cierto que el OP no propone esa acepción en sus propuestas, pero la pregunta es bastante abierta y por eso lo incluí . Las dos acepciones que uso son del Merriam-Webster y creo que merecen discutirse las dos para responder a la pregunta. Estoy en desacuerdo sobre que "fuck" añade "una capa de sarcasmo". Toda la expresión es usada en sentido _irónico_ y el uso de "fuck" añade fuerza y expresividad (de forma malsonante), que no sarcasmo. No es el uso de esa palabra, sino la intención o el contexto lo que da el sentido irónico o sarcástico.

Comment: Encontré media docena de explicaciones en el internet del elemento de sarcasmo en esa frase.  Voy a ver si nos ayudan en ELU.

Answer (score 4):

**As fuck** se suele utilizar para enfatizar el adjetivo anterior:

**Awesome as fuck, cool as fuck, rich as fuck...**

En la jerga española diría que es *jodidamente bueno, jodidamente aburrido...*

**Edgy** significa inquieto, tenso o nervioso. Su significado y sinónimos en [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/edgy):

> *Synonyms*: aflutter, antsy, anxious, atwitter, dithery, edgy, goosey, het up, hinky [slang], hung up, ill at ease, insecure, jittery, jumpy, nervy, perturbed, queasy (also queazy), tense, troubled, uneasy, unquiet, upset, uptight, worried

Así que **edgy as fuck** lo utilizaría como *jodidamente inquietante, extraño, oscuro, nervioso*; pero como lo inquietante a su vez provoca controversia, también puede ser que despierta curiosidad, ya sea por ser muy vanguardista o por ser provocador.

Comment: I don't like the adverb "jodidamente". It is very used on media to translate "fucking", but in actual speak I almost never heard it. I think some other expressions are more natural like "raro de cojones".

Comment: @Flamma for me is quite common, maybe another regionalism?

Comment: @Laura Where exactly? I have lived on many places on Spain and I never heard it on a real life conversation (only in TV and movies dubs).

Comment: Esta respuesta no es correcta.  Mira el comentario que puse con la respuesta de @diego.

Comment: This is missing the most common meaning of edgy, especially with the "as fuck" added. See https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=edgy

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "bravo como ninguno". There's no translation (that I know of) for "as fuck"...

Comment: Como explica @giorno, "as fuck" pone una capa de sarcasmo encima de "edgy." Esta respuesta no es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

The avant garde one is the most accurate. I've seen it in context and it is used to describe people who try too hard to be different and new. There's a link here with an explaination. :

http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/edgy?full=1

'knowyourmeme' might not seem like the most reliable source, but it explains the term quite well.

Comment: Welcome to [spanish.se], Rodrigo. We suggest you to check the [tour] and [help] to fully understand how this site works. Take a look also to other questions and answers. Try your best to really answer the question and remember that proper formatting can make your answer easier to read and understand. Keep in mind that your answer has to **explain** and not simply **direct** to another article where there is a proper explanation. Do not hesitate to ask for help if you wish. Welcome again, we hope to see more of your contributions again!

Comment: I like your definition, but it's important to translate with the context, but avant garde, even sarcastically, doesn't imply the same in spanish

Answer (score 0):

Creo que las otras respuestas no están teniendo en cuenta el contexto de la expresión para la traducción. Si es una frase que estás encontrando en foros de internet, como dice el comentario de la pregunta, lo más probable es que se esté usando de modo sarcástico, y el significado real sea este mostrado en "Urban Dictionary", alguien que se cree "cool" y "hardcore" pero no lo es.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=edgy

Dicho eso, y dependiendo de lo que sea calificado como "edgy as fuck", diría que dos opciones sería "guay", usado con sarcasmo, o "malote", que ya lo incluye en su definición:

"He's edgy as fuck" -> Es un tío "super guay" 
"Dude, you are edgy as fuck" -> Tío, qué malote eres.

NOTA: No era consciente de que "malote" no es una palabra registrada en el DRAE, sino que parece argot de la juventud madrileña. Podéis encontrar más informacíon aquí:

https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/CLAC/article/download/60518/4564456547400

donde ofrecen esta definición:
**malote, malota. m. y f.** Persona que presume de mala, o de dura. Se aplica con
ironía a la gente que es más bien inofensiva y quiere dar imagen de mala.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que en el uso coloquial se podría traducir adecuadamente como "provocador", puesto que lo de buscapleitos se aproxima más al concepto de "troll" (aunque edgy y troll comparten cierta carga semántica).

Dado que se suele usar en tono de burla, quizá se pueda emplear el meme clásico de Neil deGrasse Tyson:  "Ay, sí, soy super provocador".

Comment: Valdría la pena que adiciones "el meme clásico" ya que por ejemplo para mi no es ningún clásico y por el contrario es completamente desconocido.(si es que esa parte aporta a la respuesta)

Comment: Tienes razón. Aquí está, tanto en su versión en inglés como en español: [Neil deGrasse Tyson Reaction](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/neil-degrasse-tyson-reaction)

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta el tono "coloquial" de la frase (por no decir vulgar), yo lo traduciría como "Está de los putos nervios".

Answer (score -2):

@Giorno explicó bien el concepto: *edgy* en su acepción reciente es algo que se acerca al borde de lo que es socialmente aceptable.  Pero luego *as fuck* le da otra capa de sarcasmo encima.  Como dijo Giorno, la frase completa es una reacción crítica, que se puede usar para responder a un desconocido en línea.

Pero faltó la traducción al español, que pidió user478249.  Voy a proponer algo básico pero, creo, correcto:

> atrevido como mi abuelita

Seguramente alguien podrá mejorar esto.

Comment: "As fuck" debe traducirse como algo más malsonate que "mi abuelita". "Fuck" es una palabra que no usarías delante de tu abuelita.

Comment: @diego - Tienes razón. Mi problema es una falta de palabrotas en mi vocabulario. Lo que traté de expresar con la abuelita es el sarcasmo. Pero oye, "Bravo como ninguno" tampoco tiene lenguaje fuerte....